# Reading grave stone letters in an image

Tags: image-processing

[image: Clear stone with little degradation]

<sub>(Click on image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: Headstone with limited degradation]

<sub>(Click on image to enlarge)</sub>

Is there an image processing technique that would aid in reading the letters and numbers on a grave headstone?  Most stones are etched into a relatively soft stone.  Over time the surface of the stone is eroded away leaving very shallow and indistinct writing. This makes standard edge detection of little value.

Further, many stones have living flora such as lichen growing on and in the letters. This tends to make the depression in the stone undetectable. Most graveyard custodians prohibit brushing or cleansing the stone for fear of further damage.

Such flora is often multicolored making it hard to remove with RGB filtering.  Ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Attached is a relatively 'clean' example of a headstone.

Comment: If you control the lighting when photographing the stone you can try to have the light hit from the side to create contrast in the shallow grooves.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you'll get a "universal grave stone reader". Perhaps some hints to enhance a family of similar  images.

Comment: you might like: [RTI](http://culturalheritageimaging.org/Technologies/RTI/index.html) and [PTM](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/ptm/index.html)

Comment: jpg images are full of compression artifacts. Bad choice for enhancing anything

Answer (score 14):

This provides reasonable legibility by "amplifying" a slight differential pigmentation towards a blueish tonality in the carved areas:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnOn.jpg"];
tt = Last@# - Mean@Most@# &[ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[i]];
Image@tt // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can read quite clearly:

> Elizabeth P.
>
> Wife  of
>
> W.H. Gray
>
> Died
>
> Jan 21, 1889
>
> Aged
>
> 36 Y'rs. 11 Mo.
>
> & 21 D's.

Comment: You've done great work on this, but I must chuckle at "You can read quite clearly:" followed by numerous changes as you improve your processing technique. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "Quite: 2.to a certain or fairly significant extent or degree; fairly." :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But I still doubt if she was 30 or 36

Answer (score 5):

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnOn.jpg"];

ip = ColorSeparate[i // ImageAdjust, "CMYK"][[1 ;; 2]] // ImageAdd // 
     ImageResize[#, {1800}] & // ImageDemosaic[#, "Bayer"] & // 
   CurvatureFlowFilter[#, 3] &;
GraphicsRow[{i, ip}]
```

---

[image]

No success with second picture with lichen.

Answer (score 4):

[`EntropyFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntropyFilter.html) seems useful on the first image.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnOn.jpg"];

EntropyFilter[img, 11] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using `EntropyFilter[ ]` on the image and its derivatives. The (relatively) bad results are due to the JPG compression artifacts, a really bad choice of format for improving anything.

Comment: Finally got a reasonable image. It was harder than I expected.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Nice work.  Too bad the OP will probably never see it.

Comment: Well, anyway, he is already late for giving his condolences to Mr. Gray :)

Comment: Almost perfect now. I'm pinging you because **I** can't believe the sharpness of the resulting image

Comment: @Dr.bel I don't mind the ping; I am entertained by what you could pull from that image.  I can only imagine how sharp it would be if it weren't for the 8x8 JPEG blocks!